# How to delete the move assignment operator and retain compatibility with std containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, move-assignment-operator

I have a simple RAII wrapper for managing a certain resource. Here's the interface:

```
struct ResourceWrapper
{
    explicit ResourceWrapper(RESOURCE resource);
    ResourceWrapper(const ResourceWrapper& other);
    ResourceWrapper& operator=(const ResourceWrapper& other);
    ~ResourceWrapper();

    ResourceWrapper(ResourceWrapper&& other) = delete;
    ResourceWrapper& operator=(ResourceWrapper&& other) = delete;
};
```

The problem here is that I can no longer use this class with `std` containers and algorithms as soon as I explicitly delete the move assignment operator. And obviously I do need to either delete or properly implement it, as I've just learned the hard way.

Another alternative would be to implement move assignment via the regular assignment operator, but I'm not sure how to do that properly. I suppose I need something like `std::remove_reference`? I wonder if it will remove one reference too many and incur creation of unnecessary temporary object.

Comment: you prevent moving but promote copying? sounds weird. what kinnd of resource is it?

Comment: @DavidHaim: yes, exactly. Doesn't matter what resource it is, I just want to get away with as little code as possible. I can't drop copying, but I can drop moving.

Comment: The way to drop moving is to not define it, what you have done is not "drop moving" it is "poison moving so copying rvalues is not possible". That's not the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> And obviously I do need to either delete or properly implement it, as I've just learned the hard way.

No you don't.

Your class has a user-defined copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor, so the compiler will **not** define a move assignment operator for you.

So just stop trying to delete it, and the class will be copied instead of moved.

With **deleted** move operations you cannot copy rvalues of the type, i.e. it becomes extremely difficult to use as a value type (including in containers). With **no** move operations it will just do a deep copy of rvalues, which is safe and probably what you want.

Deleting the move operations only makes sense if you want the class to be completely un-movable and un-copyable, e.g. something like a mutex type where object identity is critical, not its value. It never makes sense to have a copyable type with deleted moves.

Comment: I strongly suspect that it's not happening and the bug I'm working on is caused by the default move assignment. Guess I'll have to implement the move assignment properly to test that hypothesis?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe To test such a hypothesis (which would indicate a bug in the compiler you're using), you can simply implement the moves in term of copies: `ResourceWrapper(ResourceWrapper&& other) : ResourceWrapper(other) {}`. Notice that the latter will indeed call the copy ctor.

Comment: @Angew: constructor is not a problem, the assignment is. Isn't `ResourceWrapper& operator=(ResourceWrapper&& other) {return *this = other;}` recursion? Or will it only be recursion if I use `return *this = std::forward(other)`?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, why don't you try it? `*this = other` is assignment from an lvalue, so no recursion.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe It's not recursion, it will delegate correctly. It would be recursion if you did `*this = std::move(other)`

Comment: @Angew: I see. Wasn't sure if I need `std::remove_reference` or not.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, what compiler are you using? Unless it's more than 4 years old I would be very surprised if it is incorrectly defining a move assignment operator for you when you have user-declared copy ops + dtor.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: GCC 4.9.something from Android NDK. Not old at all.

Comment: I did what @Angew suggested, and my bug didn't disappear. So you both must be right - the implicit move operator is not the problem.

Comment: GCC 4.9 will do the right thing, so your problem is definitely elsewhere. I would guess you didn't define your copy assignment correctly.